# Why is the form unis of the verb unir used here?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

In a textbook I just read the question

> Quel est le sentiment qui les unis?

I don’t understand this. If it’s the sentiment that’s doing the uniting, why is it “unis” rather than “unit”?

I thought perhaps that a compound tense is being used, but wouldn’t it then be

> Quel est le sentiment qui les a unis?

Please can somebody explain the tense and grammar rules being used here? Thanks

Comment: Your understanding is right; either emendation would correct the textbook's error.

Comment: Ok thank you. I hoped it was a mistake.

Comment: Answering to the *why* part. This is a relatively common mistake often due to a loss off attention which causes lazy writing so the pronoun *les* is confused with the article *les* and then the instinct leads the writer to put what follows "at the plural" just like if it was a noun. The fact *unis* and *unit* are pronounced exactly the same way might also play a role here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don’t understand this

Which is perfectly understandable, because the textbook contains an error. The tense is simply *présent de l'indicatif*, and as you correctly mentioned, it should be written: "Quel est le sentiment qui les uni**t** ?".

Edit: And as Luke Sawczak wrote in a comment, "Quel est le sentiment qui les **a** unis ?" is indeed also correct. Tense here is *passé composé*.

Answer (score 3):

> Quel est le sentiment qui les unis ?

is incorrect (probably a typo).

Correct forms are:

> Quel est le sentiment qui les unit ? (présent de l'indicatif)
>
> Quel est le sentiment qui les a uni(e)s ? (passé composé)
>
> Quel est le sentiment qui les unit ? (passé simple)

The respective forms in the plural would be:

> Quels sont les sentiments qui les unissent ? (présent de l'indicatif)
>
> Quels sont les sentiments qui les ont uni(e)s ? (passé composé)
>
> Quels sont les sentiments qui les unirent ? (passé simple)